# MVC Ajax Jquery POST two different type object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am doing something like this but i have a object and other FormData to pass my Controller

```
  var discrepancy = self.newCptyReply(); 
    if ($('#UploadFile')[0]) {
        var upload = new FormData(),
            file = $('#UploadFile')[0].files[0];

        upload.append('id', self.globalMessageId());
        upload.append('discrepancy', ko.toJSON(discrepancy));
        upload.append('doc', file); 


    }           

    datacontext.saveCptyToReply(self, upload);
```

And in controller signature

```
  public ActionResult SaveCptyToReply(Guid id, Tobject discrepancy, HttpPostedFileBase doc)
```

But when it reaches Controller id , doc are ok but discrepancy is null... It has data when funciton is called..

What to do...

Comment: Are you using Knockout.js?

Comment: yes... i using knockout.js. For now i have fixed the issue with two call for controller , first with id and file and second with object for data save. but this is impact performance..